# Mysql deny drop on replication

Tags: mysql

I want ask you if is possible deny drop command in replication, i want use replication as backup and when i make mistake and delete database on master it will be replication and delete my it on all slaves. Because of this i am looking for some ways how i can  protect about this..

I just was find replication delay but this isn't good solution for me

we also have backup all binaries, but it cant be backup realtime and restore from binaries take a long time.

Thank you

Comment: at this time you want to restrict drop on replication as some one can drop table on master...after some time you will ask to restrict delete on slave and after that some one can update wrongly on master so you will restrict it also...then what is use of replication....

Comment: instead you should restrict drop rights to normal users on master server and assign on specific users as per requirement.

Comment: Delete and update can be restrict by trigger.. but this isnt not my case.. we cant restric update or delete..